# Pages disappearing from asp.net cache

Tags: asp.net, html, caching

I use shared hosting. I have set my page to be cached indefinitely. The page gets cached after the first request. However on the next day when I visit my site it is no longer in the cache and has to be regenerated.

What is happening? Is the hosting removing my pages from the cache? Or something else?

Any ideas?

Comment: Code please? How are you caching pages? It is difficult to guess the reasons.

Comment: I am just caching using the outputcache directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't a lot of details to go off of here, but here's a few ideas:

1. IIS by default will recycle the app pool every 29 hours or so, which resets at least the System.Web.Caching caches.
2. Perhaps memory or disk spaced is limited (or configured to be limited.)  Many caches are designed to kick out old items when memory is needed for something else.